# Autofilter does not filter all rows

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2016

So, I have a sheet, with a table. In said table, I have a column (Column X) with a formula that gives either TRUE or FALSE.

```
=IF(B2="","",IF(OR(COUNTIF(B2,"*/C*"),COUNTIF(B2,"CUSTA*"),COUNTIF(B2,"CUSTB*"),COUNTIF(B2,"*/F*"),W2=TRUE),TRUE,FALSE))
```

I have a piece of code that applies a filter for "FALSE" in column X.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ImportedDeliveryTimes").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:="FALSE"
```

This is the only filter being applied.
If I go in to the sheet, I can see that said criteria have been applied.

However, for some reason, it only filter out some of the results that are "TRUE".
For those cells where "W2=TRUE" results in a "TRUE" value in Column X, those rows does not get filtered out, leaving me with a mix of "TRUE" and "FALSE" even though the filter clearly shows that only "FALSE" is ticked in.

If I manually apply the filter, it all works like a charm.

I have tried swapping in the X column to both string and number values (Like "A" and "B", or 1 and 2 instead of TRUE and FALSE) but no difference.

I have tried doing it with or without using a table.

I have re-written the code in it's own sub to see if there was something else interfering (As there was a bit of code running both before and after this section), but even by doing this by itself gives the same result.

I have restarted Excel.

I have restarted my computer.

I have tried to restart my brain with coffee.

I am at a loss on what I might be doing wrong here...

If relevant, I use Excel 2016

Thanks!
Sebastian

Comment: What is the formula in column `X`? Does your table have an empty row? Does the line `MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ImportedDeliveryTimes").Range("A1").Address` return the correct range address? Have you tried just `False` without the quotes?

Comment: The formula in Column X is the first formula above.
Yes, .Address returns the correct range.
Yes, I have tried using False without any quotes

Comment: Maybe your workbook is corrupt. You can easily create a copy of your workbook without any code by using `ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Copy`. Then you can manually copy the codes and save the workbook with a different name and try to run the critical code there.

Comment: So this works. I copied the whole workbook to a new workbook without any code, only copied over the filter code and now it filters as it should.
Weird. Thanks a lot for the help!!

Comment: Just to update on this.
Once I remade the code that did the rest, I got the exact same problem. Which made no sense at all, as there is no other code affecting that sheet. Now however, the filter applied as it should when I ran it isolated. It turns out, if I had a snippet of code that cleared the data in another sheet (Which, btw, is completely unrelated to the filter sheet) before applying the filter to this sheet, the filter started acting weird. ;_;

Comment: You could try filtering in reverse.  Try `Criteria1:="<>TRUE"`

Comment: I tried to do that to see if that made any difference, but it gave the same results.
Moving the code that clears the other sheets to after the filter code seems to have fixed the issue.
Curious on why though...